# Getting values from nested JSON with a dynamic key in a database

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres database with a table that has jsonb column and each row is one big blob of json
I need to get the values in deeper level but can't access it because the key is a dynamic UUID.
Tried something like this to get the keys themselves

```
SELECT 
    json_object_keys(body::json-> '__tasks') as tasksId
FROM head.bp_instances inst

WHERE 
body ->> '__templateId' = '6666f537-a370-4ebd-b709-ccb1d04b2da3'
```

But can't figure out what to do with these UUID? Iterating through each and surely is not gonna be effective I believe.

JSON itself looks like this:

```
"__tasks": {
         "e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b": {
            "__id": "e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b",
            "path": "/items/fbdeab2c-14cd-4209-8883-11673bdd3780",
            "state": "in_progress"
          },
         "e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b": {
            "__id": "e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b",
            "path": "/items/fbdeab2c-14cd-4209-8883-11673bdd3780",
            "state": "in_progress"
          },
         "e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b": {
            "__id": "e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b",
            "path": "/items/fbdeab2c-14cd-4209-8883-11673bdd3780",
            "state": "in_progress"
          }
     }
```

I need to get values like path, state etc.

Comment: can you share the structure of the json. you'd need to understand that structure to determine the appropriate query.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Added JSON structure

Comment: Do you want one row per path/state? Or a single JSON that only contains those values? Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: You also have the same key multiple times. This is non-standard JSON

Comment: you can't have repeated keys in a jsonb column, it will get collapsed to 1 key.  your sample data is not valid. please update. Could you also update your expected result please.

Comment: Apologies for late reply, those repeated keys jus a way to show the structure, I simply copy pasted on key-value row, sorry if it complicated things.
Postgres version is 10.14 
@a_horse_with_no_name Your answer seems to be the one I needed, thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per nested item, you can use `json_each()`

```
select b.id, 
       t.uid, 
       t.item ->> 'path' as path,
       t.item ->> '__id' as item_id, 
       t.item ->> 'state' as state
from bp_instances b
  cross join json_each(body -> '__tasks') as t(uid, item)
WHERE body ->> '__templateId' = '6666f537-a370-4ebd-b709-ccb1d04b2da3'
```

Based on your sample data this returns:

```
id | uid                                  | path                                        | item_id                              | state      
---+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------
 1 | e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b | /items/fbdeab2c-14cd-4209-8883-11673bdd3780 | e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b | in_progress
 1 | e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b | /items/fbdeab2c-14cd-4209-8883-11673bdd3780 | e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b | in_progress
 1 | e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b | /items/fbdeab2c-14cd-4209-8883-11673bdd3780 | e689f2c9-e6c1-432b-8dec-968e75c8350b | in_progress
```